# How do I make apache to use the domain ssl certificate?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, encryption, ssl, certificate

**I've registered a `domain` and my hosting provider includes an ssl certificate for me.**

I've set up the A dns redirection to the `IP` where I have a linux ubuntu VPS with an Apache server installed on it.

I've tinkered with `self signed` certificates and `let's encrypt` ones to set up the web ssl using the proper directives:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile <certificate chain file>
SSLCertificateKeyFile <private key file>
```

But now I don't have the cert and key files for my domain certificate so:

Is it posible to make the virtual host to use the domain? Do I have to download cert files and place them as I've done with the let's encrypt ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need the certificate files for TLS to work.

If your hosting provider includes a certificate, you should contact him about the key files.

Just upload them to your server and **make sure to set proper permissions**.

The configuration in apache works exactly the same as with your letsencrypt certificates.